# javascript quotes inside quotes, string literal issue

Tags: php, javascript, string

I am trying to display text in a javascript tooltip

I keep getting unterminated string literals even though:
a) the quotes are being slashed, b) there are no line breaks

The text I am trying to display is:

```
"No, we can't. This is going to be terrible."
```

(its a quotation from an individual and I want those quotes to display in the tooltip)

My tooltip function works like this

```
onMouseOver="Tip('string here')"
```

After I run the string through my function to clean for javascript

```
function jschars($str) {
        echo preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", addslashes($str));
}
```

It comes out looking like this in HTML:

```
onMouseOver="Tip('\"No, we can\'t. This is going to be terrible.\"')"
```

This gives me the error unterminated string literal for the first \ in Tip('\

I'm guessing its because im trying to put quotes directly inside the single quotes, how can I get around this for situations like this? (I have tried htmlspecial chars, such as replacing the " with & quot ; - I still get the error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because you're putting double-quotes inside the value of an XML (or html) element:

```
<div onMouseOver="Tip('\".......
```

the back-slash doesn't escape it from the context of xml/html.  Technically, you'll need to entity-encode the string (after you javascript-escape it).  Something like this:

```
<div onMouseOver="Tip('\&quot;No, we can\'t. This is going to be terrible.\&quot;')" >
```

Various browsers may or may not deal with that properly.  A *much* better way to approach it would be to give the element an id (or a class, or some other way for you to select it), then add the mouse over handler from a standalone script.

Answer (score 4):

Because of the structure of what you're doing:

```
onMouseOver="Tip('string here')"
```

...you have to do **two** things:

1. As Lekensteyn said, you need to use `htmlspecialchars` to turn any special HTML characters into character escapes. It does things like turn `"` into `&quot;`, which means you can safely enclose the attribute in `"` characters.
2. But you're not just using this as an attribute, you're *also* putting it inside a string literal, which means you also need to do JavaScript escaping on the string. Otherwise, (in your case) a single `'` character or backslash will mess up the string. So your `jschars` function also needs to (in order) A) Convert `\` to `\\`, B) Convert `'` to `\'`. That's the minimum, anyway, really you need a thorough "make this safe to put inside a JavaScript literal" function. From your question, I sort of had the impression you were doing this manually, but better to automate it for consistency.

**Off-topic**: Separately, I would recommend moving away from using attributes to attach handlers. Instead, look into `attachEvent` (IE) and `addEventListener` (W3C), or better yet look at a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) that will smooth things out for you. For instance, attaching a mouseover handler to:

You can use this handler to handle the mouseover:

```
function handler() {
    Tip('Your message here');
}
```

...which you then hook up like this with raw DOM stuff (obviously you'd make a utility function for this):

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
if (div.attachEvent) {
    // Uses "onmouseover", not "mouseover"
    div.attachEvent('onmouseover', handler);
}
else if (div.addEventListener) {
    // Uses "mouseover", not "onmouseover"
    div.attachEvent('mouseover', handler, false);
}
else {
    // Fallback to old DOM0 stuff
    div.onmouseover = handler;
}
```

Here's how Prototype simplifies that hook-up process:

```
$('foo').observe('mouseover', handler);
```

Here's how jQuery does:

```
$('#foo').mouseover(handler);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `htmlspecialchars()` for this purpose. The problem is ", but HTML won't understand javascript quoting, so it stops at `\"`.

```
function jschars($str) {
        echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: That solves half the problem, anyway. Although from the question, I *think* he's already manually handled the second half.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the string in javascript instead of HTML. eg:

```
<a onmouseover="Tip(this, 123)">choice</a>
```

Then something like:

```
var texts = {
  123:"No, we can't. This is going to be terrible.",
  ...
};

function Tip(elm, txtId){
  showTip(elm, texts[txtid];
}
```